# Access Button inside DataTemplate in WPF ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I want to access the Button inside MouseDown event, I have the following:

XAML:

```
<ItemsControlx:Name="icName" MouseDown="icItems_MouseDown" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button x:Name="btnName" Tag="{Binding ItemName}"</Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

C#:

```
private void icName_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       ???
    }
```

How can I access to the button from ItemsControl MouseDown event

> ex: MessageBox.Show(ItemName);

Thanks

Comment: The button in disable mode

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve here. Why do you want to access the Button?

Comment: About your disabled button you should do what I proposed in your other question. No way around it :) You can mark my other answer as correct too

Comment: @Clemens I have ItemsControl that display the items as button, some buttons may shown as disabled Item, I want to access to this button by click and hold on this disabled button but I could not able to access to button events while it in disable mode. So I'm trying to get it using button parent,  that is what I want to accomplish.. hope this clear

Comment: @Emad Regarded to the disabled button I found the correct solution as I mention you in that questions. I dont need any text box.

Comment: @jstreet I want to get the item information ex:ItemID

Comment: @Clemens In my business logic its necessary

Comment: @jstreet Lets say I want to open window with item information

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following sample code.

```
private void icName_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ContentPresenter cp = e.OriginalSource as ContentPresenter;
    if (cp != null && VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(cp) > 0)
    {
        Button button = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(cp, 0) as Button;
        //do whatever you want with the Button here...
        if (button != null && button.Tag != null)
            MessageBox.Show(button.Tag.ToString());

    }
}
```

---

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icName" MouseDown="icName_MouseDown" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btnName" Content="Button" IsEnabled="False" Tag="{Binding ItemName}"></Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need access to the button, but only need the item name from the bound item, then personally I would add the handler inside the datatemplate, I'm using a grid below.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icName" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid MouseDown="icItems_MouseDown" />
                    <Button x:Name="btnName" Tag="{Binding ItemName}"</Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Then you can access your datacontext from within the handler.

```
    private void icName_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       var item = (YourItemType)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
       var itemName = item.ItemName;
    }
```

You also don't need the tag at all

Answer (score -1):

You can't handle a click on a group of buttons and know which one is clicked. You should handle the click for each button with the same handler like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnName" Tag="{Binding ItemName}"  MouseDown="icItem_MouseDown"></Button>
```

Then the `sender` is the calling button:

```
private void icItem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   var btn = sender as Button;
   if(btn!=null)
       MessageBox.Show(btn.Tag);
}
```

Comment: Again, The button is in disabled mode